# How to split string value to Array list value (Total Array size is 300) using java sample program

Tags: java, arraylist, split

I have create a sample program in java .The concepts is split String value to generate Array list in one by one its means total string is input below:

Step one Total size:

```
Sting numberlist ="1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890........................1234567890";
ArrayList aList= new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(numberlist.split(",")));

for (int i = 0;i<aList.size();i++)
{
    System.out.println(" new number-->" + aList.get(i));
    // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"number    is"+aList.get(i),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

I got the answer +alist.get(i) = 300 ,Than Step two know i having total size 300 
The process is split the value one by one means

Display First 100 value  1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,.....

Display Second 100 value 1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,.....

Display Third 100  value 1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,.....

Sample programs is:

```
    String numberlist="1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890........................1234567890";

    int splitNumber = 100;
    int length = numberlist.length();
    ArrayList<String>splitList = new ArrayList<String>();
    int splitCount = 0;

    for(int i = 1 ; i<= length;i++)
    {
        splitCount++;
        boolean last = false;

        if(i==length)
        {
            last = true;
        }

        if((splitNumber == splitCount) || last)
        {
            String number = numberlist.substring(splitList.size()*splitNumber,i);
            number = number.endsWith(",") ? number.substring(0,number.length()) : number;
            number = number.startsWith(",") ? number.substring(1,number.length()) : number;
            splitList.add(number);
            splitCount = 0;
        }
    }

    for(String number : splitList)
    {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Display First 100 value"+number);
    }
}
```

but something wrong  in the program  don't know where is the problem anyone given me solutions.

I need my output is below:

Display First 100 value  1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,.....

Display Second 100 value 1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,.....

Display Third 100  value 1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,.....

its like one by one..

Note : sorry my grammar mistake..

Comment: people why minus  this question ?

Comment: You seem to unclear what is exactly the question, based on reading I THINK you mean to split a arraylist based on every 100th value, but this very unclear noted

Comment: As @Ferrybig says, you question is unclear, please read this [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by your question, I assume the number of elements is divisible by `splitNumber`. There are a few approaches to this. Here I show one using modulo to create groups of size `splitNumber` and `int` division to get the group number:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String numberlist = "1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234";
        int splitNumber = 3;
        ArrayList<String> splitList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(numberlist.split(",")));

        if (splitList.size() % splitNumber != 0)
            throw new Exception("Number of elelemnts not divisable by split number");

        for (int i = 0; i < splitList.size(); i += splitNumber) {
            System.out.print(((i / splitNumber) + 1) + " group of " + splitNumber +": ");
            for (int j = 0; j < splitNumber; j++) {
                System.out.print(splitList.get(i + j) +", ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1 group of 3: 1234, 1234, 1234, 
2 group of 3: 1234, 1234, 1234, 
3 group of 3: 1234, 1234, 1234,
```

Perform your own formatting.

Comment: but i having error java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index  103, size is 103  my total size is 103   in the number list   i given  an                 split number =100                   First split the 100 correctly remain 3 value can't be split error will be occur error java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: @visualprocess A list of size 103 will have index numbers from 0 to 102.

Comment: How to declare the 0 to 102 in the conditions

Comment: @visualprocess I already showed you in my answer. And you are changing the conditions in your question: now your list size is not divisible by `splitNumber`, so you will need to handle the remainder yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly.. You can display 100 elements and whatever is leftover like this.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i += 100) {
        if ((i+100) > s.length()) {
            System.out.println(s.substring(i, s.length()));
        } else {
            System.out.println(s.substring(i, i + 100));
        }
    }
```